# PHP mkdir - Why is this an invalid argument?

Tags: php, date, mkdir

I wanted to experiment with creating directories titled with the date and current time. I know I can use the php time() function, but that is hard for me to read. Why can't I create a directory named 06-11-2014 11:37:04 or so? The php mkdir function is giving me an invalid argument when I try to use this format.

php code

```
<?php
$newdate = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");

mkdir($newdate, 0755, true);

?>
```

Comment: Because of `077` use `0777`; you forgot a `7`. Better yet, use `0755` it's safer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hm no luck with 0777 or 0755, still getting invalid argument.

Comment: Most filesystems won't allow colons in a file or directory name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The colons in the date are messing it up. Your best bet is to use a format like this:

```
$newdate = date("m-d-Y H_i_s");
```

Comment: That was it! I will accept your answer when I can. My filesystem doesn't allow colons in the directory title.

Comment: This is due to the linux file naming convention.

Comment: Sidenote: My (hosted) server is Linux and using colons worked fine for me. Must be the way it's setup too, which I have no control over.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Yeah I just tested it out. I'm using a windows server and when you have colons in the name of a directory it automatically removes them.

Comment: @wheatfairies I think it's a good thing too, because and by experience, if I create a file containing colons on the server then try to upload it to my computer (which is Windows-based), Windows will throw me an error. Characters I hardly or never use are hyphens, spaces and colons when using filenaming conventions, yet alone in code. *Cheers*

Answer (score 3):

You have this:

```
mkdir($newdate, 077, true);
```

But it should be:

```
mkdir($newdate, 0777, true);
```

But that said `777` permissions are a security risk. You are better off using `775` or `755` instead:

```
mkdir($newdate, 0755, true);
```

The problem with `777` permissions is it means 100% of anyone who has access to your system can read, write or execute anything in that directory. That is just opening a door to either headaches later on if you get hacked or even inadvertent headaches like you yourself mistyping a path & wiping out data you shouldn’t have wiped out.

File & directory permissions should not be just opened up to anyone in the world with `777`.

**EDIT:** The original poster says they are still are experiencing  problems even with corrected permissions. My only suggestion is to change the code from this:

```
$newdate = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
mkdir($newdate, 0777, true);
```

To this:

```
$newdate = date("m-d-Y_H-i-s");
mkdir($newdate, 0755, true);
```

I believe the issue is that a file or directory name with `:` in them will just choke on some systems like Mac OS X. Also I placed an underscore (`_`) between the date and time.

Comment: I didn't get any luck with that, but I will definitely use 0755 now. Any other ideas?

Comment: You see Jake, another reason why I use "comments" ;-)

Comment: That was it, the file naming didn't allow me to have colons in the directory names.